# Delete query not working (db.delete, db.exectSQL, db.rawQuery....)

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-database

I am trying to remove certain rows of a table in Android. I tried running directly through the SQL command "execSQL" and "rawQuery". Right now I'm using "db.delete" where I step in the argument "where" the rows that I want to remove.

This is the code:

```
String where = DBTables.TActivities.ID + " NOT IN ( " +
                " SELECT " + DBTables.TInscripcionesActividades.ID_ACTIVIDAD + " FROM " +DBTables.TInscripcionesActividades.TABLE_NAME + " );";

db.beginTransaction();
db.delete(DBTables.TActivities.TABLE_NAME, where, null);
db.endTransaction();
```

I tested the sql petition in a BBDD browser and it works fine.

I want to delete all records of the table "TActividades" except the activities whose IDs are in the "TInscripcionesActividades" table.

Any ideas?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us how you instantiated your db object. Also what do you mean by not-working? Are you seeing any error?

Comment: No, any error but rows are not removed. Object db is properly instantiated as all remaining requests are working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `setTransactionSuccessful()` before `endTransaction()` for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
String where = DBTables.TActivities.ID + " NOT IN ( " +
                " SELECT " + DBTables.TInscripcionesActividades.ID_ACTIVIDAD + " FROM " +DBTables.TInscripcionesActividades.TABLE_NAME + " );";

db.beginTransaction();
db.delete(DBTables.TActivities.TABLE_NAME, where, null);
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```